# Undesired vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

Here is a simple HTML example, where the bottom container has a (possibly unjustified) vertical scroll bar in Chrome, as opposed to Firefox.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100px; width: 300px; border: 1px solid black">
  <div style="background-color: burlywood; overflow-y: auto">
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: cadetblue; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div>Test1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Rendering in Firefox]
Rendering in Firefox (65.0.1)

[image: Rendering in Chrome]
Rendering in Chrome (72.0.3626.119)

What is the proper rendering and what could be the cause of confusion in interpretation between these two browsers?

Edit: How should this vertical scroll be avoided? That is the main question here.

Comment: @JamesDouglas In accordance with CSS rules, there can be only one proper rendering.

Comment: That is not an element of the webpage, the scroller is browser generated so every browser generates a personalized one, there is no right one, they are different because these are two different browsers with different controls

Comment: @nano The appearance of the bottom scroll is being discussed here. The browsers should be implemented so the same standards are honored. In any case, I will edit the question to ask how to avoid the scroll, because that is the main goal here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's an issue of standards compliance. It looks like a glitch in Firefox.

Here are three pieces of supporting evidence:

1. Even though the scroll bar doesn't appear on the lower box in Firefox, the scrolling function still works. Simply hover over the box and use the mouse's rolling device to scroll up and down. Scrolls normally; you just can't see the scroll bar.
2. Switch from `overflow-y: auto` to `overflow-y: scroll`. This should force a scroll bar to appear at all times. In Firefox, it doesn't. But the scrolling function still works with the mouse.
3. Occasionally, for reasons I cannot yet ascertain, the scroll bar does actually render on the lower box in Firefox.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container > div:first-child {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

#container > div:last-child {
  overflow-y: auto; 
  /* test this:  overflow-y: scroll;  */
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Test1<br>Test1<br>Test1<br>Test1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, I am still looking for a solution, I want to avoid the scroll in bottom panel, since for this case it makes sense only for the upper container to have a vertical scroll. The layout should probably be reorganized and/or CSS changed, but not sure how.

Comment: Well, it's not supposed to be hidden always, just in the presented case. The number of items could vary.